# How to add .tex file with beamer to the main one?

Tags: beamer, documentclass

I want to add a presentation to the main file, for which I need to define `\documentclass`. I tried to do this using `standalone`, but the presentation itself looks like plain text and I also get an error `Undefined control sequence. \frametitle`

My code: 
main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \input{sub}
\end{document}
```

sub.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Some background}
        
        We start our discussion with some concepts.
        
        \pause
        
        The first concept we introduce originates with Erd\H os.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This example is a bit contrived, obviously, as you can just use `sub.,tex` as-is. You might be better off trying to add the necessary frames from your presentation using `\includegraphics[page=X]{sub}`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possibility 1:

Include as text

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}

\subfile{sub}
\end{document}
```

#### Possibility 2:

If you want the result to look like beamer, you could use `tcolorbox` like this:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\tcbinputlisting{
  comment only,
  pdf comment,
  freeze pdf,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
  listing file=sub.tex
}

\end{document}
```